# "browse oldfiles" doesn't show anything

Tags: vim

when I run `:browse oldfiles` I only get this:

[image]

I expected the list of the last opened files. Any help?

Comment: The `oldfiles` list comes from the variable `v:oldfiles` which generated from `~/.viminfo`, maybe you can have a look at that variable and file to see if any problem occurred. Also make sure that you have r/w permissions to that file.

Comment: @Jaege I have just open that file, but I cannot find anything about `v:oldfiles`.

Comment: try `:echo v:oldfiles` in vim, you should see a list. And also check `:set viminfo?` to see the option `'n` of how many files that you saved marks.

Comment: @Jaege `echo v:oldfiles` just return `[]`, and `:set viminfo?` returns`viminfo='100,<50,s10,h`

Comment: Well, `[]` empty list means you don't have an old file list generated from `viminfo` file. Is there any file history store in your `viminfo` file?

Comment: @Jaege this is the content of `~/.viminfo` file: https://gist.github.com/Ziiweb/3000d96c6f8b7b36561b

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100559/discussion-between-jaege-and-ziiweb).